# How can I put the action of CardHeader right beside the title?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this card title where it is in the middle of it. And the `IconButton` was located at the right edge of the screen. How can I put the `IconButton` right beside the title?

Currently, it looks like this:
[image]

below are the codes:

```
<CardHeader
        title="List of Items"
        action={
          <Tooltip
            title={<h3>.....</h3>}
          >
            <IconButton aria-label="help" color="primary">
              <HelpIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        }
      />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `title` is a node

```
function Title() {
  return (
    <div>
      List of Items
      <Tooltip title={<h3>.....</h3>}>
        <IconButton aria-label="help" color="primary">
          <HelpIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
<CardHeader title={<Title />} />
```

[image: Edit beautiful-booth-koucx]

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by "since `title` is a node"?  I am new to MUI and am not clear on how your solution follows from that statement.  Thx :)

Comment: @JJL I mean that `Title` is a react node, so you can pass it as title prop in `CardHeader` component.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `CardHeader` is your component and not 3rd party library:

1. If `CardHeader` accepts `title` as string prop, then you should go into `CardHeader` itself to have tooltip accepted via `props`
2. If `CardHeader` accepts `ReactElement` then you can construct title within this component where header is used and pass it down
3. Extend `CardHeader` so it has tooltip text accepted via props and conditionally render it (if that prop is passed to it)

Assuming that it comes from `material-ui`. It already accepts title as `node`, so you should be able to do:

```
<CardHeader
        title={<>
          "List of Items"
          <Tooltip
            title={<h3>.....</h3>}
          >
            <IconButton aria-label="help" color="primary">
              <HelpIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </>
        }
      />
```